# Got JWT Token from Azure AD B2C but getting 401 error in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm implementing Azure AD B2C in a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 app.

I've already created the Azure AD B2C tenant and registered my app, etc.

After I login, I get redirected to the URL I specify and I see the token in the URL but I get an error stating the app requires authentication -- see below:
[image]

I saw a few similar posts and what I gather is that the token is automatically validated by the middleware. Is that not so?

What do I need to do at this point?

The code I included in my app are as follows:

In `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
   options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
   jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
   jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
   jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
   {
       OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
   };
});
```

In `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs`, all I have is `app.UseAuthentication();`

In my controller, I'm also using `[Authorize]` to make sure my actions are not open to anonymous users.

What am I missing? How do validate the token and get the claims?

Comment: One question to you before I write an answer: Is your app an API or an app with a UI that a user interacts with? Because you are mixing JWT Bearer auth (for APIs) with an id token returned from interactive authentication (used by interactive apps).

Comment: It’s a ReactJs SPA app with ASP.NET Core API backend so there’s only one page where the JS file for all front end is downloaded. The rest is API. I’d like to use only JWT authentication- even for the Index page - to keep things simple.

Comment: Alright, that's another common pattern. JWT authentication middleware won't read the id token in the fragment. You are going to have to use MSAL.JS (or other supported OIDC library) to authenticate user on client-side, and then attach the id token as an access token to each request as a header.

Comment: What about my Index page then? That's the entry point to my front-end app and I want to make sure that I give it to only authenticated users.

Comment: Currently that isn't really available directly. I suppose you could somehow make something that validates the id token in the fragment, but usually the static files for the app are not considered valuable.

Comment: What's the common approach in these situations then? Mix cookies with JWT? Even in that case, I'm only getting a `jwt` token from Azure AD B2C. Is there an example code that I can follow?

Comment: The typical approach is to use the id token to authenticate in the front-end, acquire additional tokens with hidden iframes + implicit grant if needed (MSAL.js does this). Then you attach tokens to calls to APIs and the APIs use JWT authentication. Front-end uses session or local storage to store information, so no cookies are needed.

Comment: So, if I'm following you correctly, in my case, I let the user download the `js` code for my React client. Then, using `MSAL.js`, I get the token and keep using the app. If the token is missing, I'd handle that in my frontend client. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the typical approach :)

Comment: Great! One last question before I thank you from the bottom of my heart :-) Do I not need to validate the token coming from Azure AD B2C? Is that also handled by `MSAL.js`?

Comment: That should be handled by MSAL. Though that said, any measures to validate the token in the frontend can be worked around since it is running outside of your control, on a user's device. The important one is the API authentication and authorization.

Comment: And my API will automatically validate token, correct?

Comment: It will download the OpenID Connect metadata document from AAD B2C at startup, and get the signing keys from there. It will check various things on the token and confirm the signature is valid, the issuer is valid, and the audience is what you set. Authorization is of course something you still need to handle. So things like can this user call this endpoint and read a given resource.

Comment: So yes, it will validate it :D

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really appreciate it. if you could enter something as the "answer", I'll accept it. I'd like you to get credit for your help. Again, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining our discussion here as an answer.

The typical approach to this kind of app is that you allow unauthenticated clients to download the HTML, JS, and other static content.

Then the front-end can use MSAL.JS to authenticate the user.
The front-end SPA will get an Id token which tells the front-end who the user is.
MSAL.JS also allows you to get access tokens to call APIs.
It uses hidden iframes + the Implicit Grant flow to do this.
That access token will then need to be attached to requests to the API as a header (`Authorization: Bearer token-goes-here`).

MSAL.JS will use session or local storage to store the tokens (this is configurable).
So no cookies are used in this setup.

Then the back-end API should authenticate the access token it receives in the header.
What you have there is already sufficient to authenticate the token.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
   options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
   jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
   jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
   jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
   {
       OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
   };
});
```

The JWT Bearer authentication handler will load the OpenId Connect metadata document on startup from the authority configured here.
That allows it to get the B2C tenant's public signing keys among other things.
This info allows the handler to then validate access tokens as they come in without interacting with B2C in any way.
It checks the signature is valid, the issuer is valid, and that the audience in the token is what has been configured.

Authorization is of course not handled by the authentication handler, so you must then also check that the calling user actually is allowed to access the resource they are accessing.
The user id is available in the access token.

MSAL.JS may have done some validation on the token as well (I can't remember right now if it did), but doing validation in the front-end is something that can be worked around by anyone with control of the user's browser.
Validation on the API side is the most important piece.

Comment: Kept running into issues so I created a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with React front end using the built-in template in VS 2017 and I'm still getting a 401 error. Removed all the complexities of my existing app to make sure something else is not causing the problem. Posted a new question with all the necessary code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418406/asp-net-core-api-returning-401-on-call-from-react-client