# ASP.NET Core API returning 401 on call from React client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.1 SPA app with React/Redux front end. I've implemented `jwt` authentication which gets its token from Azure AD B2C.

When I analyze the network tab for my API call to the backend, I see that token is placed in the header -- see below:

[image]

Here's the code for my fetch call:

```
import { fetchOptionsGet, fetchOptionsPost, parseJSON } from '../../utils/fetch/fetch-options';

export const getData = () => {

    return (dispatch) => fetch("/api/accounts/test", fetchOptionsGet())
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.ok) {

                parseJSON(response)
                    .then(result => {
                        // Do something here...
                    })
            }
        })
};
```

Here's my fetch options:

```
export const fetchOptionsGet = () => {

    const token = authentication.getAccessToken();
    debugger
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authentication": "Bearer " + token
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `debugger` in the above code to make sure I'm getting the token which confirms I have the token -- not to mention it's my network call as well.

Here's the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
             options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
         jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
         jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
         jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
         {
              OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
         };
     });

     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

     // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
     services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
     {
         configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
     });
}
```

Here's the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
       app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    ScopeRead = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ScopeRead"];
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
           spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
     });
}
```

Here's the API controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
}
```

I put a break point right at the beginning of my `Test()` API method but I'm not hitting it. Without the `[Authorize]` attribute, I'm able to hit the `Test()` API method and get my data. So, something in the pipeline is blocking the call before I even hit the API method.

I also tried specifying the authorization scheme in my API controller with the following but that didn't make any difference. Still getting a 401 error.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Any idea where I'm making a mistake here?

Comment: There’s probably something useful in the output -> debug window.  See anything?

Comment: Have you put a break point on your OnAuthenticationFailed handler?

Comment: The header name should be `Authorization`.

Comment: @Brad You have the eyes of an eagle my friend!!!! You got it. That was the problem! Now it works nicely. Could you please post your response as an answer so that I can accept it. I'd like you to get credit for your help! I can't thank you enough buddy! I've wasted so much time on this. Thanks again!!!

Comment: In my case, [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] makes all difference. Thanks, now its working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header name should be `Authorization`.

```
export const fetchOptionsGet = () => {

    const token = authentication.getAccessToken();
    debugger
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token //<--
        }
    }
}
```